# Python Exception not working, ValueError (exception bucket)

Tags: python, exception

```
import math, random

try:  
    class Circle:
        def __init__(self, radius):
            if radius == 0:
                self.radius = random.uniform(1.1,2.5)
            else:
                self.radius = radius         
        def clc(self):
            return math.pi * 2 * self.radius

        def dia(self):
            return self.radius * 2 

        def area(self):
            return math.pi * (self.radius ** 2)

        def dia2(self):
            return self.radius * 4


    circles = []

    for i in list(range(0,2)):
        s = int(input("enter te radius of the circle : "))
        c = Circle(s)
        circles.append(c)

except (ValueError) as e:
    print('There was an error, try again ?') 
    print('You keyed a char insted of a number:',e) 
else: 
    print("radius:", c.radius,
          "cirm:", c.clc(),'Diameter:',
          c.dia(), 'area:', c.area(),
          'dia2:', c.dia2())
```

Comment: Your code's indentation is messy; please try to fix it so we have a better idea what you're actually trying to do :).

Comment: Can you give me a example of how to use ValueError ?
i tried 
Try:
               except ValueError as e: 
                          print("")

Comment: I think(?) you're using ValueError fine, but I don't know what your code actually looks like because the indentation is messed up. Try fixing it so I can give a better answer :).

Comment: Dose it look Fixed now ?

Comment: Unfortunately not. Try fixing it in a text editor, then copy/paste it into the question editor, select the entire text of your code, and click the Code Sample button (the one that looks like `{}`).